# Running "Hello World" electron app in linux

Tags: node.js, linux, centos, electron, chromium

I want to run "Hello World" electron app in linux (CentOs). I have this folder structure for my app

[image]

When I run npm run start, in turn runs electron .

I see the following error

```
[10948:0114/140415.407127:FATAL:setuid_sandbox_host.cc(157)] The SUID sandbox helper binary was found, but is not configured correctly. Rather than run without sandboxing I'm aborting now. You need to make sure that /home/staff/kjeeva/simple_electron_app/node_modules/electron/dist/chrome-sandbox is owned by root and has mode 4755
```

Comment: Please replace the screenshots with text, otherwise people won't be able to find this question when they search for the error message

Comment: It happened to be app was opening with the same git issue https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/13984

Comment: I found out that electron-prebuilt is replaced with electron! but my app window atleast electron-prebuilt but with electron it doesn't even show up on the screen

Answer (score 2):

cd  ./node_modules/ electron/dist/

sudo chown root chrome-sandbox

chmod 4755 chrome-sandbox

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/17972